# VBA/Excel: Flow Chart Formula

Tags: excel, vba

I'm sorry if this question is vague or answer exists, but struggling to find what I'm looking for.

I have created a sheet (VBA generated) where the user is required to fill in certain cells in a table. As multiple users are going to be editing the document, I want to automate a 'flow chart' type answer to standardize the document.

I.e. if in the first cell the user input is "No", then the remaining cells in the table default to "N/A". If the input is "Yes", then the user moves on to filling out the next box in the table. I was also going to use a drop down list to ensure the correct user input.

Does anyone have any suggestions of what I can research for a method to achieve this? Was thinking of having the cell formula, but this will delete after user input so wanted a method where the formula would remain even if the user input is deleted.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Maybe a userform and lots of VBA?

Comment: I considered a userform / input box, but unsure how to trigger this. The sheet just displays a table where they can look for information (I can modify the table, but it is tricky as a lot of code was required to get it to it's current stage). 

Not sure if I could maybe create a trigger in the first cell? I.e. if they type "Start", the userform loads. Going to investigate.

Comment: Maybe open it on the `Worksheet_Activate` event:  `Private Sub Worksheet_Activate(): Dim frm As New UserForm1: frm.Show: End Sub`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be to use the worksheet_change event. However your problem is you are creating the sheet programatically. If you are using a template for your sheet you can just attach the code to the template, other wise you will have to create the code in your workbook and use the Workbook_sheetchange event

```
 Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If Sh.Name = "sheet1" Then
    If Target.Address = "$A$5" Then   'I'm assuming cell A5 is your first cell, change as required

       If UCase(Sh.Range("a5")) = "NO" Then
              Sh.Range("a10") = "#N/A" 'repeat for all cells you want to be NA
       End If
    End If
End If
End Sub
```